# How is the cross-product transformation defined for binary features?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, recommender-system

I am reading the paper on Wide & Deep learning and for the wide component, it states that one of the most important transformations is the cross-product transformation. This is defined as follows:

$$\phi_{k}(\mathbf{x})=\prod_{i=1}^{d} x_{i}^{c_{k i}} \quad c_{k i} \in\{0,1\}$$

Then, the authors argue that for binary features, a cross-product transformation (e.g., “AND(gender=female, language=en)”) is 1 if and only if the constituent features (“gender=female” and “language=en”) are all 1, and 0 otherwise.

But how does this relate to the given formula? And how can I think of the cross-product transformation in general?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's do this in the opposite order of how you asked.  i.e. first:

## How can I think of the cross-product transformation in general?

For me a [cross-product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) comes from linear algebra, and it is a different transformation.  Therefore let's start by not confusing both.  The cross-product in the equation above is a transformation alright but is not related to what most of us call a cross product.

With that out of the way let's look at the formula.  Since both the index on the product and components of $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{c}$ are the same (they're all $i$), we can be rather confident that $d$ is the number of dimensions/features we are working with.  Therefore to make things a little easier to see let's work with $d = 4$:

$$
\phi_{k}(\vec{x})=\prod_{i=1}^{4} x_{i}^{c_{k i}} \quad c_{k i} \in\{0,1\}
$$

Now we can write an example vector to which we apply the transformation, say:

$$\vec{x} = [7, 5, -0.5, 0.2]$$

And an example vector which parametrizes the transformation:

$$\vec{c} = [0, 1, 1, 0]$$

And for a start let's evaluate the transformation:

$$\phi_k(\vec{x}) = 7^0 \cdot 5^1 \cdot -0.5^1 \cdot 0.2^0 = 5 \cdot -0.5 = -2.5$$

And that's it.  But now comes the important part, let's describe what this transformation just did: We took a vector in 4 dimensions, took it's 2nd and 3rd components and multiplied them together (whilst we ignored the 1st and 4th components).  In other words **the transformation $\phi_k$ uses its parametrization $\vec{c}$ to decide which components of its argument to product together.**

We can therefore use different parametrizations to achieve different transformations of the vector $\vec{x}$.

What this may be useful for? If you are confident that all components in the vector are $> 1$ (or all are $< 1$) then you have the combined magnitude of the selected dimensions.  Although keep reading below since this is really useful to binary features.

---

## How does this relate to the given formula?

i.e. how the binary features can only be 1 if all (relevant) features are present.  I believe that this relates to the definition of $0^0$ and $0^1$.  Let's take a different vector:

$$\vec{x} = [0, 1, 0, 1]$$

Let's say that these are non-exclusive binary features: [male?, dog?, white?, fed?].  So we have a *female dog which is not white and is currently well fed*.

Now let's take the parametric vector to be:

$$\vec{c} = [0, 1, 1, 0]$$

And perform the transformation:

$$\phi_k(\vec{x}) = 0^0 \cdot 1^1 \cdot 0^1 \cdot 1^0 = 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 0 \cdot 1 = 0$$

A small note is now in order: $0^0 = 1$ is not true in all fields of mathematics, but since it is accepted in most fields and makes sense here we will use it here (and so I believe that the authors of the paper do use this assumption as such).

**Wait!  So had we had the dog been white we would have had a $1$ as the result.**  In other words, had $\vec{x}$ been $[0, 1, 1, 1]$ we would have gotten $1$ as the result of the transformation because the third term would be $1^1$.  Try it out!

This means that **$\phi_k$ with $\vec{c} = [0, 1, 1, 0]$ will return $1$ (true) for all $\vec{x}$ that represents a white dog, does not matter if the dog is male or female or whether it is fed.  And will return $0$ for anything that is either not a dog or not white.**

In other words, the parametric $\vec{c}$ defines the features *that matter* (the ones in the vector $\vec{c}$), and such a parametrized transformation $\phi_k$ return true if all the features *that matter* are true in the argument of the transformation ($\vec{x}$).

The big difference in the binary features is the fact that $0^1 = 0$, which binds the entire product to $0$.  Whilst $0^0 = 1$ and $1^1$, which results in a dimension/feature whose value does not matter for our transformation.

---

P.S. I prefer physics notation for vectors, a component of a vector is $x$ but a full vector is $\vec{x}$ instead of $\mathbf{x}$.  Please bear with the notation.

Comment: Thanks, @grochmal for the clear answer.